# Laravel 5: get route parameters in associative array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Can I return all of route parameters in associative array, excluding normal GET/POST parameters?

sample:

```
route: user/{id}
requested url: user/1?test=bla
required array: Array ( [id] => 1 )  //exclude normal GET variable value "test"
```

I know I can use `request` methods: `route()` & `__get()`, but they need me to know the variable key before use them:

```
$request->route('id')
$request->__get('id')  //Its value will be changed if normal get variable has same name passed
```

I need to return associated array with all passed parameters in route,
thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Route::current()->parameters();
```